# DELETE method not being used on sign out in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have Devise set up in my Rails application, but my sign out link:

```
<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
```

is not working. The correct HTML seems to be generated:

```
<a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out">Sign out</a>
```

but there is no DELETE request being logged by Rails, only a 'GET /user/sign_out', which then throws an exception. What could be causing this?

**Edit:**

I've now discovered if I use `button_to` instead of `link_to` this works, so the issue certainly seems to be with the DELETE call not being generated client-side.

Comment: How did you declare your devise routes ? Do you have similar issue when you delete a user  ?

Comment: Route is devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'users/sessions' } (I've extended the session controller but this issue seems unrelated as I tried it without this too).

Comment: Ah, checking deleting a user I've discovered the same issue when using link_to, but there are no issues for either using button_to.

Comment: is this working ? `<%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, data: { no_turbolink: true } %>`

Comment: Thanks but no. I'm using Turbo so just tried data: { turbo: false } too, but no luck yet.

Comment: I've worked it out, for some reason rails-ujs wasn't installed. Thanks for the help.